# How can I format a CString variable that the result is a table with 3 columns?

Tags: mfc, format, multiple-columns, cstring

I'm working with MFC Aplication in Visual Studio 2013 and i want to format a variable CString to appear in columns in a edit control box.

I already add a variable CString to the edit control box, but i can't format the text to appear in columns.

This is my code:

`val=_T("column1         column2          column3")
cycle for
val.Format(val+_T("%-15ls%-20s%-15ls"),val1,val2,val3);
 val = val + _T("\r\n");
end of cicle for`

That code is in a For cycle where val1,val2 and val3 are CStrings variables and change in each iteration.

My result is this:

`colum1               colum2               colum3
hello world           transform               ice cream
hello               google                 pizza
my name is Ze           transform               ice cream`

And i want:

`colum1               colum2               colum3
hello world          transform            ice cream
hello                google               pizza
my name is Ze        transform            ice cream`

can you help me?

Comment: You can only do this if the font used in the edit control is fixed pitch such as "Courier".

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You save my life. It worked. I changed the all font of the mfc aplication and it worked. It is possible to change only the font in the edit box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font must be fixed pitch such as "Courier New".

To change the font of the edit box do this in `OnInitDialog`:

```
CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
CFont *pf = pEdit->GetFont();
LOGFONT lf ;
pf->GetLogFont(&lf);
_tcscpy(lf.lfFaceName, _T("Courier New"));
m_Font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
pEdit->SetFont(&m_Font);
```

and put

```
CFont m_Font;
```

in the declaration of your dialog class.

Comment: It didn't work. I put the code in OnInitDialog and it gave me some small errors. I had to change two things: _tcscpy to wcscpy_s and CFont m_font to CFont m_Font.

With this change the code runned without any problem but it didn't change any type of font. Maybe, because I add a variable to the editor box which is a CString. There are another way to change the type of font?

Comment: I did it! Thank you for the help. I was putting the code in the wrong place. I had only to change the two things that I said before and it work. Than you for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems not all controls are updated after set a Font. What style have you set for the CEdit control?

Try manually Update after SetFont(&mFont);

```html
pEdit->Invalidate(); 
pEdit->UpdateWindow();
```

(I can not comment a comment above, so my comment to above is here)